# K Nearest Neighbor

Tags: android, mysql, machine-learning, nearest-neighbor

As part of my final project for a 1 year software development course i am required to implement a knn project which predicts the outcome of football matches in an android app.
I built a mysql database on an online hosting site (byethost) using predictors:
difference in average goals per game
diff in average points per game
diff in average goals conceded per game
outcome

My tutor recommended k should equal 100 and that a significant data set be constructed (over 1000 results)

From here on i am lost as to how i should approach the problem at hand. Can anyone give any further guidance as to how to tackle the problem.

All advice is welcomed.

Comment: About homeworks: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

K-NN could be used as part of the solution.  However, it is an undirected data mining algorithm, meaning specifically that it doesn't generate expected outcomes.  That means that K-NN is not appropriate as the only technique used for a final project that depends on prediction.

I am concerned about any year-long course that makes such a recommendation.  The difference between directed and undirected algorithms is pretty fundamental.

Comment: i had suggested poisson distribution however my project supervisor advised knn as it was a short algorithm which could easily be reused. after creating an enormous  database of prediction indicators and the outcome i am at a loss as to how to code this solution or even import the data from the mysql database into the app to perform the algorithm?